# Programming Python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, python, database, raspberry-pi3

I recently got a Raspberry Pi for use with a college project, I'm fairly well versed coding Python but not with Raspberry Pi's unfortunately. What's the best compiler for Raspberry Pi app creation? What I need it to do is connect with a database and another application I have developed for Android. Is it possible to do this? Or am i better to program it on my PC and FTP the files across?

Comment: Notice Python is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) (as opposed to compiled). Check [this](http://raspberrywebserver.com/sql-databases/using-mysql-on-a-raspberry-pi.html) link and see if it helps you (it uses mysql python bindings). As for your application one would need to know how is the application made and what do you expect from the connection.

Answer (score 2):

A **Raspberry Pi** has already **Python** installed, so if you have already some experience programming with Python, it will be no different than in any other computer. The easiest way to start is using **IDLE**, you'll find it on the desktop or on the applications menu. Here's a [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python/) to the official documentation

Another option is working remotely via ssh (I personally prefer this way because these small devices are normally slower). Follow this [link](https://nathanpjones.com/2016/02/remote-debug-gpio-on-raspberry-pi/) to set the environment up.

As per the connection to the database, that would depend on where is it located. If your raspberry acts as a server to the Android app, then you could access it straight from your program, if it's in a third-party server, then you might need to implement a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

To use **Python** on the Raspberry Pi,
Create a ***.py** file, then open terminal and type

```
python [insert name of file here].py
```

And you're set! Python is a great language that is also great on the Raspberry Pi. To answer your other question, I prefer using SSH / SFTP over my network and will modify the Python files that way.
 The only difference between the RPi and a x86-64 installation of Linux is that some of the packages you need might be harder to find (so watch out for that), but other than that, it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for on the Raspberrry Pi is memory usage.  I tend to have lots of browser tabs, terminal windows, etc. running.  Pi gets very unhappy (i.e. slows to crawl) when it runs low on memory.  Even a long scroll-back on Idle can do it (e.g., logging lots to the shell)

I put the resource monitors on the top right of the task bar - memory usage shows in red.  As it approaches the top, it's time to close some things!

Right-click on task bar, select "Add / Remove Panel Items", "Panel Applets", "Add", scroll down to "Resource Monitors", select and "Add".  It defaults to showing CPU, so click "Preferences" and click "Display RAM usage", "OK", "OK"